# TypeError: Task.find is not a function in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am having an issue with my model.I am connected to MongoDB and my server is running fine.
But am unable to route through the TaskController.Is the error because of the model or with the find() function.
I don't know exactly how to fix it.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks

tasks.js

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const router=express.Router();

// const TaskModel=mongoose.model("taskslist");

// const Task=mongoose.model('Task');

const Task=require('../model/task.model');


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{

   Task.find({},(err,docs)=>{
       if(!err){
           res.render("tasks",{}
           );
       }
    else{
        console.log('Failed to retrieve the Course List: '+ err);

    }
   });

});

module.exports=router;
```

app.js

```
const TasksController=require('./controller/tasks');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index',{});
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,"/views/"));
app.set("view engine","hbs");
app.engine("hbs",expressHandleBars({
    extname:"hbs",
    defaultLayout:"mainlayout",
    layoutsDir:__dirname+"/views/layouts"
}));

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("server listening");
});

app.use("/tasks",TasksController);
```

task.mode.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

var taskSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

title:{
    type:String,

},
isDone:{

    type:Boolean,
}

});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Task",taskSchema);
```

Comment: ***task.mode.js*** is this a typo?

Comment: check your import of task.model is same as your task.model file name probably it could be reason of error because you have given name `task.mode.js` to file and imported `task.model`

Comment: Are you sure that you are running find query on the model. If you are exporting the schema, and running find on schema wont expose find function.

Comment: That was a typo error here, but I have given correct name.

Comment: Then how to retrive the data from mongodb??Without using find

Answer (score 0):

you missed mongoose.conect(db)
you can try something like this  -

```js
         let taskjs=require('./task.js')
         let express=require('express');
         let mongoose=require('mongoose');
         let app;
         let db;
         let http
        let taskSchema
        let isDoneSchema
         port=process.env.PORT || 3000;
         http = require('http').createServer(app);
         http.listen(port);
         db="mongodb://localhost:27017/YourCollection";
         mongoose.connect(db);//you missed this one
         Schema=mongoose.Schema;
         
         titleSchema=new Schema({
         type:String 
         })
          
         isDoneSchema=new Schema({
         type:Boolean
         });
        task= mogoose.model("Task",titleSchema);
        isDone=mogoose.model("IsDone",isDoneSchema);
        taskjs(app,task,isDone)
        
        
        //and now in task.js
        
        module.exports=(app,task,isDone)=>{
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index',{});
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,"/views/"));
app.set("view engine","hbs");
app.engine("hbs",expressHandleBars({
    extname:"hbs",
    defaultLayout:"mainlayout",
    layoutsDir:__dirname+"/views/layouts"
    
}));

/////
///now you can access the mongoDB on any route //////
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

   Task.find({},(err,docs)=>{
       if(!err){
           res.render("tasks",{}
           );
       }
    else{
        console.log('Failed to retrieve the Course List: '+ err);

    }
   });

});

        }
```